# res.json() sends data in the form of res.data but accessing _id within it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I'm having trouble understanding why a res.json call in my app sends data (an order object) but when I try accessing a piece of that data (res.data._id) and storing it into a variable I get it as undefined. I know this piece of data exists since the console.log shows the order object's _id value but console.logging that particular piece returns undefined. What causes this behavior?

Backend logic:

```
router.post("/new", function(req, res) {
    const productInfo = req.body.productInfo;
    let order = new Order();
    order.product = {
        _id: productInfo.id,
        name: productInfo.name,
        description: productInfo.description,
        price: productInfo.price,
        quantity: productInfo.quantity
    }
    order.status = "Created";
    order.total = productInfo.price * productInfo.quantity;
    order.owner = {
        id: req.body.id,
        username: req.body.username
    }
    order.save().then(order => {
        res.status(200).json(`Order created successfully! Created order details: ${order}`);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Order create error: ", err.message);
    });
});
```

Frontend logic:

```
let orderID = "";
return (
    <PayPalButton
          createOrder={(data, actions) => {
            axios.post("http://localhost:4000/orders/new",
                {productInfo, userID, username}
            ).then((res) => {
                if(res.status === 200) {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    console.log(res.data._id)
                    orderID = res.data._id;
                }
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                  currency_code: "USD",
                  value: props.amount
                }
              }]
            })
          }}
     />
)
```

console.log response:

```
Order created successfully! Created order details: { product:
   { _id: '5e68330c8dcfa56868f1d23a',
     name: 'Birdhouse',
     description: 'A beautiful birdhouse',
     price: 5,
     quantity: 2 },
  owner: { username: 'tgoandrex' },
  createdAt: 2020-04-12T23:04:46.286Z,
  _id: 5e93a16eb1cbc837d80167ef,
  status: 'Created',
  total: 10,
  __v: 0 }
undefined
```

Comment: you are not sending the order in the response dummy, look at this line `res.status(200).json(\`Order created successfully! Created order details: ${order}\`);` i think you are probably sleepy!

Comment: You're right, I was asleep on the wheel. I even had the solution to this for my product creation component. Thanks for straightening me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`axios` is expecting the endpoint to return a JSON object, but you're sending a string to the client:

```
res.status(200).json(`Order created successfully! Created order details: ${order}`);
```

Attempting to access `res.data` on the client will give you the string literal

```
"Order created successfully! Created order details: [elided]"
```

But because this is a string, the property `_id` does not exist on it, and so it will return `undefined`.

In order for this to work, you need to send *just* the object, rather than a string:

```
res.status(200).json(order);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `/orders/new` endpoint doesn't respond with JSON but with a simple string. Express's `Response#json` method is expecting an object that will be serialized to JSON, not a string.

You should just pass your order as single argument to the `json` method:

```
res.status(200).json(order);
```

otherwise, your React app won't be able to parse the JSON since it isn't a valid JSON format.